# How long will a variable be stored in a deployed node/express application? and will it be available to every client?

Tags: node.js, express, variables, server

I have a let variable that is declared at the top of a node/express file and assigned a value through a post request, this variable is then accessed by a different get request to return a value to the client. My question is: how long will this variable be stored if not overwritten & will that variable's value be available to a request from another user?

i.e

```js
let variable;

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
      // returns an object
    },
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({ success: false, reason: "session didnt work" });
      } else {
        variable = object.variable
        res.json({ variable.id: variable.id });
        // res.status(200).send({ success: true });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That variable exists in the scope of the module it is declared in and it lasts for the duration of the nodejs process.  It is available to any request handler from any user in that module.

I call this a "top level module variable".  It's like a module-global, available to any code in that module for the lifetime of the app, not available to any code outside the module.

> how long will this variable be stored if not overwritten

For the lifetime of the nodejs process.

> will that variable's value be available to a request from another user

Yes.  It is scoped to the module so any  code running the module (regardless of what user triggered the code) will have access to the same variable.

Nodejs does not have "per user" or "per request" variables by default.  Request-specific data is on the `req` object and user-specific data is typically created by using a session object that is indexed by a cookie that is sent with each request and then looked up using that cookie index.

Comment: so say the post request creates a session object, and then that session object is assigned to the variable, will the variable still be available across users with a get request?

Comment: @Ren - Yes, it would be available to all users.  But, you should not do that in the first place.  The only type of data that should get assigned to top level module variables is data that SHOULD be accessed by requests from all users.  You can logically think of these as GLOBAL variables (though they are scoped to the specific module, not to all modules), but they are available to any code in that module running on behalf of any user.  Session objects should be stored in a session store, indexed by a key that is specific to the user so that only that user accesses that session.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to add a cookie or json web tokens!

Answer (score 2):

Although not recommended to have global variables for many reasons;
If you ask for how long that variable will be there: for lifetime
If you ask for how long the variable value will be there: until get's overridden
You still have to think that the respective variable will be always with an empty value until it is assigned some value by some function. I found some  good articles [here](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/)  and another good one [here](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html)

Hope this gives a bit of clarification!